# How does "+" work in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a seemingly simple question that I'm asking for the sake of better understanding how domain specific languages work in R.

How does the generic function "+" allow one to build a layered plot in `ggplot2`?

Obviously `ggplot2` works at a very high level of abstraction. Could someone show a simple example showing how "+" works under the hood with `ggplot2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`methods("+")` will show a starred `"+.gg*"`, non-exported from ggplot2.

```
ggplot2:::`+.gg`
```

will reveal the beast.

Edit: to clarify, `+` is a generic function in base R, and anyone can define their own method for a specific class. The ggplot2 package internally defines it for objects of class `gg`; it is not exported in the package Namespace so a little convincing is required to expose its source code, e.g. with `getAnywhere("+.gg")`.

Comment: is `+.gg*` a method in base R? It's asterisked as "Non-visible"

Comment: You would not expect it to be in "base R". Perhaps you mean to ask is it an S3 orS4 method? If it's visible via `methods()`, then its S3.

Comment: got it. In order to build something like ggplot2 requires extensive use of R's object oriented system (S3 in particular) - something not discussed often.

Comment: "requires" is too strong a word. OO is a nice thing to have in your toolset, but you know the saying about the hammer and the nail.